# Is the double word necessary in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, commas, sentence

Can anyone let me know if I can replace the second 'problems' (at the last of the sentence) with the word 'them'? I prefer not to use the word 'problems' twice in my sentence.

They too faced the day-to-day problems of life and did not perform supernatural feats to solve their problems.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could reasonably use "them" to replace "their problems" in the above context.

Comment: @Hot Licks Agreed. *them* can only refer to the previously mentioned *problems*.

Comment: thanks to both of you.